# mvc 5 react.js compiler error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, sitefinity

I cannot seem to figure out what is causing the compiler error below. Currently working with Sitefinity CMS and their Feather API, and Visual studio 2015.

Also, React.js MVC 4, Server side rendering

Here is my view:

```
@model SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.SlideModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Milliken Floor Covering Banner</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.React("BannerContainer", new
   {
       initialData = ViewBag.slideData
   })

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/Banner.jsx")"></script>
    @Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSX:

```
var BannerContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                Hello
            </div>
            );
    }
});
```

Here is the error message:

```
11/13/2017 11:10:22
Type : React.Exceptions.ReactScriptLoadException, React.Core, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9aed67b161f7db78
Message : Error while loading "~/Scripts/Banner.jsx": Compile error: Syntax error
   at 4:13
Line: 4
Column: 13
Source : React.Core
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void EnsureValidState()
HResult : -2146233088
Stack Trace :    at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.EnsureValidState()
   at React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.GetEngine()
   at React.ReactEnvironment.<.ctor>b__15_1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at React.ReactEnvironment.get_Engine()
   at React.ReactEnvironment.EnsureUserScriptsLoaded()
   at React.ReactEnvironment.CreateComponent[T](String componentName, T props, String containerId, Boolean clientOnly)
   at React.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.React[T](HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String componentName, T props, String htmlTag, String containerId, Boolean clientOnly, Boolean serverOnly, String containerClass)
   at ASP._MVC_Views_Banner_Index_cshtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MlkFcWeb\obj\CodeGen\MVC\MVC\Views\Banner\Index.cshtml:line 12
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at RazorGenerator.Mvc.PrecompiledMvcView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.ControllerWrapper.Execute()
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.ExecuteController(MvcProxyBase proxyControl)
   at Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Infrastructure.Routing.FeatherActionInvoker.ExecuteController(MvcProxyBase proxyControl)

Additional Info:

MachineName : FCSitefinityDev
TimeStamp : 11/13/2017 4:10:22 PM
FullName : Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities, Version=10.1.6527.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131550628790146894
ThreadIdentity : Anonymous
WindowsIdentity : FCSitefinityDev\matiasmariani
Requested URL : http://localhost:60876/


Category: ErrorLog

Priority: 0

EventId: 9010

Severity: Warning

Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling

Machine: FCSitefinityDev

App Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131550628790146894

ProcessId: 8680

Process Name: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe

Thread Name: 

Win32 ThreadId:6692

Extended Properties: 
----------------------------------------
```

Any ideas? Suggestions? I'm a blind and not seeing something?

Answer (score 0):

In your view are you missing?

```
@using React.AspNet
```